# Generic "Collection" with class based implementations

Tags: java

I've the following requirement:

1. There are different types of messages that are collected. Each message must return a html string for its visualization
2. Each message type must be grouped in a collector. This collector must also return html. The html of the collector is a table, where each row is added via `message.getHtmlFormat()` for every message added to the collector. Note that each collector class has a different html representation, same as every message class
3. The analyzer itself keeps track of all message collectors. At the end, it generates html and adds each collectors html to the body.

At the end my design looks like this:

```
    List<MessageCollector<? extends Message>> collectorList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    MessageCollector<OrderMessage> orderMessageCollector = new OrderMessageCollector();
    OrderMessage orderMessage = new OrderMessage();
    orderMessageCollector.addMessage(orderMessage);

    MessageCollector<PartnerMessage> partnerMessageCollector = new PartnerMessageCollector();
    PartnerMessage partnerMessage = new PartnerMessage();
    partnerMessageCollector.addMessage(partnerMessage);

    collectorList.add(orderMessageCollector);
    collectorList.add(partnerMessageCollector);

    StringBuilder htmlMail = new StringBuilder();
    htmlMail.append("<start>");
    for (MessageCollector<? extends Message> collector : collectorList) {
        htmlMail.append(collector.getHtml());
    }



public interface Message {
    String getHtml();
    int getSeverity();
}



public interface MessageCollector<T extends Message> {
    void addMessage(T t);
    String getHtml();
}


public class OrderMessageCollector implements MessageCollector<OrderMessage> {
    List<OrderMessage> orderMessageList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void addMessage(OrderMessage orderMessage) {
        orderMessageList.add(orderMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHtml() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("<tableDummy> .....");
        for (OrderMessage orderMessage : orderMessageList) {
            stringBuilder.append(orderMessage.getHtml());
        }
        stringBuilder.append("<end> .....");
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Is it a valid design for a class to implement one specific generic type for an interface? Is there a better pattern to solve my requirement?

Comment: What concerns do you have about your design?

Comment: Can you elaborate why do you need the messageCollector interface? Seems like the implementation is pretty specific and straight forward, you add messages and then call getHtml. Will there ever be a different approach?

Comment: INMHO I think you don't need the generic type at the moment, It's just making your solution more complex since you have the `Message` interface which defines the `getHtml` method

Comment: @SamuelNegri Because the "analyser" will store all finished MessageCollectors in a collection. Then at the end it has to loop over all of them and get their html representation. Without the interface I cannot store them all in one collection. Except by using a base clase and overriding the getHtml. Would that make more sense? But then again, it would somehow have to only accept the specific message type in addMessage

Comment: @eHayik The collections is another wrapper over the Message interface though. It will add html, add the messages html, and then adds html again. And each collection does that differently

Comment: @tgdavies The generic in regards to Message seems like a bad design. But it might also be totally valid. I mean it works

Comment: The way your code is at present, you could move `addMessage` out of the `MessageCollector` interface and put it on the concrete classes, replacing declarations of `MessageCollector<OrderMessage>` with `OrderMessageCollector`. But I think that having it on the interface is a useful prompt for implementors of `MessageCollector`, and expresses an intention regarding your architecture in a compile-time-checkable way. So I would not change your design at this point.

Comment: @tgdavies Do you think public abstract class MessageCollectorBase<T extends Message> would maybe make more sense? With an ArrayList of messages as a member variable, addMessage implemented by default and abstract getHtml? This would of course lock it more to the concrete storing implementation